# Single entry Cyprus Visa

Tags: romania, cyprus

Can a single entry “c short stay visa” use to directly enter to romania? Because i am planning to go to romania but i still didn’t received a validation from them for my visa application and i saw that there is slot for a cyprus visa. Would it be possible to use a “single” entry cyprus visa to romania?

Comment: Are you planning to go to Cyprus? If not, applying for a visa there is deception or should be declined if honest about the reason to apply there.

Answer (score 3):

No, you need a valid Schengen visa with two or multiple entries to enter Romania without a Romanian visa.

Additionally, if your sole goal is to visit Romania, then you cannot apply for a visa from a Schengen country just for this.

Comment: What about bulgarian single entry? Can i directly go to romania and after to bulgaria?

Comment: That's a different question, but as worded in the regulation, yes, any Bulgarian C visa would allow entry into Romania. But again, you need to justify to Bulgaria that you actually have a plan to visit Bulgaria, a reason to do so, provide an itinerary, etc. It would not be completely unexpected from them if you provide your actual itinerary to ask for the Romanian visa (and say you would then not need a Bulgarian visa), though.

Comment: Yeah of course i’ll have all the documents for justification i just wanna make sure only if i will be able to use a single entry bulgarian visa

Comment: The [Romanian Ministry of Foreign Affairs](https://www.mae.ro/en/node/2040) and the [Decision No 565/2014/EU](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/PDF/?uri=CELEX:32014D0565&from=EN) both say "short-stay visa" from Bulgaria without more details, so I can only suppose yes. Timatic says "_Passengers with a “C" visa issued by Bulgaria or Cyprus, valid for the period of intended stay. They are visa exempt for a maximum stay of 90 days. Information: The maximum stay is granted within 180 days_" Note the validity issue: Bulgaria could grant you a visa for the dates of travel to Bulgaria.

Comment: So i can only use that bulgarian visa in romania without going to bulgaria?

Comment: If they issue a visa with just the travel dates you requested for Bulgaria, then you could only enter Romania during those dates. So you would need to include your time in Romania in your dates pretending you want to be in Bulgaria at that time, and that would be fraud, which can have consequences ranging from just not getting the visa to being banned for deception. I'm afraid that if you want to travel to Romania, the only good option is to get a visa from Romania.

Comment: But i will not be able to go to bukgaria with the single entry visa since i used it to enter romania right? I mean i can go go Bulgaria by car but i am not sure if i will be able to enter since i am holding a single entry visa.