# Crossing Romania border from Kiyv with Ukranian permanent residency

Tags: transit-visas, buses, romania, ukraine, cyprus

I am a Lebanese with permanent residency in Ukraine. I have a single entry to Cyprus and since there are no airport, i want to return to Lebanon through bus or train. Is there a way without having to get a visa in the consolate. Can I cross the border of romania or bulgaria without a visa to them.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Single entry Cyprus Visa](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/184085/single-entry-cyprus-visa)

Comment: OP, your question is quite unclear. Please provide a more detailed itinerary.